# Android get difference days between two dates return wrong days

Tags: android, date

I have 2 methods to get the difference of days between 2 dates.
The first is:

```
public static int getDiffDays(Date dateOne, Date dateTwo){
        Long timeOne = dateOne.getTime();
        Long timeTwo = dateTwo.getTime();
        long diff = timeOne - timeTwo ;
        return (int) (diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    }
```

The other one is:

```
public static long getDiffTimeUnit(Date dateOne, Date dateTwo, TimeUnit unit){
        return unit.convert((dateOne.getTime() - dateTwo.getTime()), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
```

Both methods return me a wrong value when the dates have 1 day of difference, otherwise they return the right value.
So for example with these 2 dates:

> Mon Aug 01 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2022
> Tue Aug 02 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2022

They return me 0 day of difference instead of 1...

But with these 2 dates:

> Mon Aug 08 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2022
> Wed Aug 31 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2022

They return me 23 days of difference that is correct.

How can I resolve this issue?
(I cannot use ChronoUnit because it requires API 26)

Thank you

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

[image: Example 3]

[image: Example 4]

Comment: Could not reproduce the error. Please share a minimal test code.

Comment: The functions I shared with the dates I shared returns me the difference of days I shared. So for example 01/08/2022 with 02/08/2022 returns me 0 instead of 1 ^^

Comment: @ocos I shared 2 screenshots

Comment: A quick demo. https://pl.kotl.in/upAgXTPvV

Comment: @ocos ok thank you, but I shared you my screenshot and on my computer I get 0 as result and I don't know why

Comment: Firstly, I thought you are providing the same dates for dateOne and dateTwo. It is hard to detect the error from screenshots but your screenshot 1 shows that there is a `diffDays = 7` between Sep 01 and Sep 09. Screenshot 2 indicates `diffDays = 0` between Aug 01 and Aug 02. Is the `getDiffDays()` method is exactly you shared? That method seems to decrease the difference by 1 day. Can you put a print statement for dateOne and dateTwo in `getDiffDays()`.

Comment: @ocos yes the method is the same and the dates are different. I share a screen inside diffDays

Answer (score 1):

The code you shared `getDiffDays` is working fine.

You told us that

- dateOne is "Tue Aug 02 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2022"
- dateTwo is "Mon Aug 01 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2022".

However in the last screenshot,

- `dateOne` has a timestamp of 1659391200000.
- `dateTwo` has a timestamp of 1659304800196.

So, `dateTwo` is Aug 01 plus 196ms.

The difference between those days is 86399804. Nearly a day but not. `86399804 / 86400000 is 0` in integer's arithmetic. This is why you get 1 day short.

Here a piece of code for demo purposes.

```java
long timestamp = 1659391200000L; // Tue Aug 02 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2022
      
Date date_2Aug = new Date(timestamp);
Date date_2Aug_plus_196ms = new Date(timestamp + 196L);
            
System.out.println(date_2Aug); // output: Tue Aug 02 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2022
System.out.println(date_2Aug_plus_196ms); // output: Tue Aug 02 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2022

// let's see the date with milliseconds
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
String formattedDate2Aug = sdf.format(date_2Aug);
System.out.println(formattedDate2Aug); // output: 02/08/2022 00:00:00.000+0200

String formattedDate2Aug_plus_196ms = sdf.format(date_2Aug_plus_196ms);
System.out.println(formattedDate2Aug_plus_196ms); // output: 02/08/2022 00:00:00.196+0200
```

When you give a date "Mon Aug 01 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2022", I expect a date with timestamp of 1659391200000.

**This is why sharing a minimal test code is important.** Screenshots may drive us to wrong conclusions.

Comment: Hello thank you for you answer, but as you can see in the screenshots the dates I pass the function is 01 August and 02 August on midnight GMT +2.
So why the timestamp is incorrect?

Comment: Also I get the dates from the DB (So i couldn't share a minimal test code, that's why I shared the functions) and I convert those dates (that are in the format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z')" to the format: "yyyy-MM-dd". So the seconds and milliseconds should have gone after the conversion :/ Why I get 196 milliseconds more?

Comment: Hello, are you there? ^^

Comment: I solved by forcing the set of the milliseconds to zero so now "getDiffDays" works fine. But I still don't understand why the date doesn't "lost" his milliseconds part when I formatted it to "yyyy-MM-dd" as it should be. Do you have any clue about that?

Comment: `> ... I formatted it to "yyyy-MM-dd"` Let's have an object which holds a person's age. i.e years=21 and months=9. You can write age formaters which show the same age like : 1st function floor => 21, 2nd ceil => 22, 3rd 21y9m. Formatter does not change the value of person's age. It is always 21 years and 9 months. This is same for date formaters. Your getDiffDays function is working as expected. You may check timestamp value in database rows, or any method updates the dates.

Comment: ? I have the datetime (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) when I format it to date only (yyyy-MM-dd) the "time" part is cutted off so the date changes from, for example, 2022-10-10 09:50:11 to 2022-10-10 00:00:00. So yes the values changes but it cuts off the Hours, Minutes and Seconds part as I setted in the formatter but it doesn't truncate the milliseconds part. Why? It should set the milliseconds part to 0 too as specified in the formatter.

Comment: So, you are `parsing` a date string from database to create a date object and in the code flow the date's timestamp changes. As a final comment, I would suggest you print `date.time` in every step that date used to find if there is any code logic alters timestamp.

Comment: Mh I don't directly parse a date string to get a date object. I already get a Date Object thorugh Gson when I get the response from the server then I change the format of the date object so I have a yyyy-MM-dd date instead of a datetime yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS. The "time" part (hours, minutes and seconds) is removed from the resulting date object, but the milliseconds part isn't. So the timestamp doesn't change, the number of millisecond is the same I get from the server but the milliseconds part should be truncated when I change the formatter of the date like it happens for hours, min & secs